# sh404sef 301 redirect persist even after url is deleted

Tags: redirect, joomla, url-rewriting

I ve searched for the url in sh404sef_urls table and in the cache files under com_sh404sef/cache, it's well deleted, but even so when I type it it still does a 301 redirect to another sef url, when I check for aliases for the later I find nothing ... is there any other place sh404sef does do some caching ?

Comment: Aside from clearing cache, you should be aware that 301 redirects are *permanent*. Your browser *caches* them and sometimes even if the redirect is removed the *browser still perform them*. Make sure you try another browser (not incognito/private mode or whatever) to fully test it.

Answer (score 0):

based on your configuration, sh404 caches in

- all `/cache/sh404sef_*` folders
- `/components/com_sh404sef/cache/shCacheContent.php`

plus it logs useful information in

- `/administrator/components/com_sh404sef/logs`

If you delete it, sh404 may be configured to wild guess and will recreate it every time.

If you want to make sure it goes somewhere, even a 404 page, you need to find it in the URL Manager or 404 Manager, and edit its url. Deleting will do no good as it will be re-created next time it's requested.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but some users find this and draw incorrect conclusions:

> If you delete it, sh404 may be configured to wild guess and will recreate it every time.

This is incorrect. sh404SEF strictly has no mechanism to automatically create any redirect. You seem to be confusing SEF URLs and 301 redirects, which is what the OP is talking about.

About possible reasons:

- As @ahmad-alfy mention, a usual cause for this is browser caching.
- another common cause is that the redirect is NOT done by sh404SEF, but either by another joomla extension, or more commonly by the web server (.htaccess or similar)

301 redirects are not "cached" in any way by sh404SEF. They are stored in the alias table, as you already checked. If not there, and except for a few things like auto-redirect from non-sef to sef, non-www to www or vice-versa, incorrect URL case, and shURL, there is no other storage of redirects.
If you checked that, then most likely, sh404SEF is not doing this redirect.

Rgds